Regular expression to match an optional group in the middle of a string
I have a regex question that's been driving me a bit crazy. I'm parsing a file and need to match and extract specific parts of each line read. The lines come in two forms (ignore the syntax, I'm just simplifying), specifically:
foo.add("/some/path", class::someFunction)
foo.add("/another/path", class::someOtherFunction, HttpMethod.POST, class::yetAnotherFunction)

I need to extract the "paths", and if there is that HTTP POST, I need to detect that and extract it.
The regular expression that I was able to figure out that works is:
foo\.add\(\"(.+)\",[^,]+(,.+POST)?

That works for both lines, but I don't know how to do the same thing without using [^,]+. Meaning, if I wanted to make the regex more generic and work for even longer lines, say something like:
foo.add("/other/path", class::firstFunction, class::secondFunction, class::thirdFunction, HttpMethod.POST, class::yetAnotherFunction)

then the "until you see a comma" character group wouldn't work for all three strings, unless I added more and made them optional. I tried the following regexs (and other variations), but they're either too greedy or too lazy:
Too greedy: foo\.add\(\"(.+)\",.+(POST)?
Too lazy: foo\.add\(\"(.+)\",.+?(POST)?
I feel like I'm missing something. I believe the second .+ is the culprit, but I thought I could make it more lazy with ?, but then it only matches one character I think (according to https://regex101.com).
Is there a way to say "match EVERYTHING from here until you either

hit the end of the line or
find the optional POST, in which case detect it and save it in the second group"?

I tried different regular expression, had to settle on one that seems too prescriptive.

Just don't do it with regex

Use two different regular expressions, one for the simple format, the other for the format with POST.

Is this what you need?

foo\.add\(\"([^"]*)\",(?:.+,\s*(.+POST))? will work, too. The idea is always like this: wrap all the optional part with an optional non-capturing group (using a greedy ?) and then use a capturing group to get what you need inside it.
